# In electron how do I load a URL as my launcher instead of a local file

Tags: javascript, electron

I am developing an ELECTRON Application, I was wondering if I could load a URL instead of a File inside of Package.json ("main": "Loader.js",)

I've tried replacing the file with a URL and it says it can't find the App!

```
{
  "name": "passgen-dev-build",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Developers Build for PassGen",
  "main": "http://rossm.pw:8080/Builds/development/loader/Loader.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^2.0.3",
    "electron-winstaller": "^2.6.4"  },
```

I expect that Electron accepts the URL and loads the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> expect that Electron accepts the URL and loads the app

You cannot. Entrypoint of electron app is not a renderer process (chromium) but a node.js process which owns responsibility to create browserwindow. You should point local file first, and inside of that file you can point remote address via `BrowserWindow.loadURL`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll just stick to my default method.